# Get portal web address from MySite

Tags: url, mysite

Is there a way (programmatically) to get the portal web address on mysite? I want to retrieve this to put the url to a link and to redirect the search, so all users get back to the main site.

Answer (score 0):

This is not programmatically, but also as option:

> 1.In Central Administration, click Manage Service Applications.
>
> 2.Click the User Profile Service Application.
>
> 3.Click Configure Personalization Site under 'My Site Settings'
>
> 4.Click New Link.
>
> 5.Fill in an owner because that field is required. Leaving the Audience field blank means that this link will be shown to everyone.

According [My Links in SharePoint 2010](http://blogs.technet.com/b/praveenh/archive/2011/10/12/my-links-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for your response. This is a nice feature, but not exactly what I was looking for. I need to add the links to custom elements such as the logo . Also I need the link to be dynamic because this solution is going thru dev -> test -> prod. And these URL's are different.